# Is automated testing of a Nativescript app possible with Bluestacks?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, e2e-testing, bluestacks

I'd like to write a nativescript application and I'd like to test it with an android and ios emulator befor releasing it. I use bluestacks, so I thought maybe it is possible to run somehow automated tests on it. I need to test its integration with android or ios, so the push notifications, getting the GPS coords, going offline, doing HTTP requests, saving to a local storage and probably e2e testing with the GUI. Now I work on the logic, data processing, etc. which is vanilla js and I can test it easily with nodejs, but sooner or later I'll have to test the other parts too somehow. Is there any solution to make it work with bluestacks or other mobile phone emulators? Note that I don't want to use some sort of online service like saucelabs, just emulators and virtual machines what I want to do on my dev computer...

Comment: You should look into Scrcpy by Genymotion for the emulator. https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Comment: @happyvirus Thanks, I'll check it! Is there any tutorial I could use to make a development environment with automated testing very fast? I have only a few days to finish this project and I really don't want to do manual debug, it is unprofessional...

Comment: May I ask, why don't you use the iOS Simulators or Android Emulators come with Xcode / Android SDK. I don't think BlueStacks is meant for this use case, but if it's detected as a device by ADB probably you might be able to do that.

Comment: @Manoj I don't know anything about mobile app development, probably because of that. As long as it is an emulator I can run on my computer, I am ok with it. It does not have to be bluestacks. What I need is a way to e2e test my application without having to buy a new smartphone or pay for an online service. The scrcpy that happyvirus mentioned does not seem to be the solution. It needs a phone with android 5, mine is 4.1.x, it is pretty old, even nativescript apps won't run on it. Ofc. I could borrow a phone from a friend, but I'd rather do this with an emulator if possible.

Comment: You can run E2E with emulator, just go through the Testing Docs that should guide you through.

Comment: @Manoj Okay, I'll read them. I hope that helps starting with nativescript.